# Multiple Java Problem errors on importing existing maven project to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have an existing maven project which I downloaded from GitHub.

If I run `mvn clean install` from the root of the project everything works fine (a jar file is created in target folder and it executes works OK). 
But when I go to Eclipse and import this project as Existing maven project I get multiple (395 to be precise) Java Problem errors (like `The method is undefined` etc.).

The only thing that I notice is when I run maven from command line it creates `.m2` folder inside the project folder while maven from Eclipse creates `.m2` inside my `C:\Users\username` folder.

I'm using Eclipse 2019-06, Java 8 and apache-maven-3.6.1.

P.S. Same errors appear when I import this project to Intellij IDEA 2019.2.

Comment: You should link to the project.

Comment: @Dreadron Questions should be self-contained as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Olga, don't worry. Import the project into Eclipse. Then wait some minutes. If the errors do not vanish, try "ALT + F5". If this still does not help, build the project from within Eclipse ("Run As -> Maven build"), do "ALT + F5" again.

Eclipse often takes some time to fully "understand" the project, i.e. synchronise the POM and the files to its internal mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried "Maven -> Update Project" and it was the same. And I did "Maven Install" (it builds successfully) and then "Maven -> Update Project"  but still errors won't go away(